# How to autoscale Kubernetes cluster on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, autoscaling

I created kubernetes cluster on aws ec2 using kubeadm. Now I need to autoscale the K8's cluster when there are not enough resources on nodes to schedule new pods, How can I achieve autoscaling feature for my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I`m new for AWS. But I used [KOPS](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-cluster-autoscaling-on-aws/) for GCP using this tutorial as reference. I don't think it is possible to make CA (Cluster Auto-scale) by kubeadm.

I hope it will help you.